# pthread API equivalents of semaphores in semaphore.h

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore, producer-consumer

This question is related to a solution to the producer/consumer problem I'm working on.  We were asked to use pthreads to solve the problem.  In order to create my empty and full semaphores for the bounded buffer, I used semaphore.h, but I was told there is a method for accomplishing this without semaphore.h.

Is there a standard method for creating semaphores using the pthread API?  That is, is there a simple equivalent to the following using pthreads only:

```
sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
sem_wait(&empty);
sem_post(&full);
etc.
```

Thanks for any info you can give me on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<semaphore.h>` functions (`sem_init()` / `sem_open()` etc. ) *are* the pthreads semaphore API.

Perhaps you are being guided towards using condition variables instead of sempahores to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, maybe so.  I asked about using semaphore.h, and was told to use pthreads instead.  Could you please explain how a semaphore can be constructed using condition variables?

Comment: Ah, never mind.  I found a good tutorial on condition variables online.  Thanks for directing me to the right idea.

Comment: @VictorBrunell, can you share the tutorial or some insights from that tutorial?